# Deployment of plugins which interact with each other

Tags: ocean, petrel

We're hoping to implement plugins which will interact, through interfaces declared in a shared assembly.  Technically, several plugins will register entities with a "main" plugin (during integration), which in turn makes use of these entities (during the Petrel session).

As each plugin typically will be distinct products on the Store, they need to be installed by distinct PIPs.

The plugins will be backwards compatible with regards to the shared assembly.

Is it possible to accomplish this with PIP installers - and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with PIP installers right now, but we have this requirement in our list, and will implement it in one of our future releases.

Comment: Thanks - not the answer I hoped for, but an answer nonetheless :-)  Experimenting, I found that as long as the shared assembly is installed only by one (i.e. the "main") plugin, and interfaces remain compatible between versions, it seems to work fine.  However, in 2011.1 use of the Plugin.Dependencies property is broken.  If a depended upon plugin is not installed, Petrel crashes at startup.